# Change Points for Normalized data

Tags: r, plot, normalization

I have a data set normalized to the interval [0,1].
I am trying to find out the change points in the data.

That is I have to find where is the starting of a spike, if I plot the data as a line graph.
The data is in this format

```
1                    0.00000000
2                    0.01617486
3                    0.01814208
4                    0.01530055
5                    0.01857923
6                    0.01595628
7                    0.01945355
8                    0.01530055
9                    0.01530055
10                   0.01639344
11                   0.01573770
12                   0.01092896
13                   0.01836066
14                   0.01551913
15                   0.01945355
16                   0.26841530
17                   0.14754098
18                   0.01726776
19                   0.01704918
20                   0.01726776
21                   0.01945355
22                   1.00000000
23                   0.08459016
24                   0.02732240
25                   0.02579235
26                   0.01551913
27                   0.01923497
28                   0.10185792
29                   0.12765027
```

After reffering a previous post, I tried this code.

```
library(data.table)
myDT <- as.data.table(t1)
myDT[,change:=t1-t1[1]]
myDT
```

but it is showing all the change as 0

```
  1:                  0.00000000      0
  2:                  0.01617486      0
  3:                  0.01814208      0
  4:                  0.01530055      0
  5:                  0.01857923      0
 ---                                   
135:                  0.12459016      0
136:                  0.10032787      0
137:                  0.10885246      0
138:                  0.16109290      0
139:                  0.44371585      0
```

Please Help me

Comment: hey @dvs, there are many R users in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ perhaps that would be a better spot to post in the future? I'll take a stab at it though...

Comment: stat.Stackexchange users suggested to post in stack overflow since it contains code

Comment: I stand corrected. See below for my attempt.

Comment: For the data.table solution, try `myDT[, change:=c(t1[-1],0)-t1[1]]`

Comment: Looks like an ECG on plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
t1["change"] <- c(t1[2:nrow(t1), 1], 0) - t1[, 1]
```

the breakdown is as follows:

```
t1["change"]
```

will add a column to your dataframe

```
c(..., 0)
```

creates a vector with items 2 to the end of your column vector.  then you subtract your column vector to get the difference.

now the one thing you need to be careful of is that 0 I placed...you'll probably get a value that you should throw away. usually when doing a running average or difference, the length of your useable data shrinks at one end of your vector depending on how you "shift" your vector or where your sliding window starts.

update: you can put NA where I put the 0 if your code checks for NAs.

Comment: One doubt,how to identify starting of a peek from this difference values

Comment: @dvs: yes, I suppose that you be your next problem! what you have amounts to a sort of cheap derivative of your function. A peak in this case would be identified by a larger positive derivative followed by a large negative derivative (possible an intermediate value in between depending on your data). So you may need to search for "zero crossings" in your 'change' column...which could be another column called change2 (second derivative, same procedure but a difference on the change column)...and look for negative values that are below a certain threshold.